# Method to classify variable based on one string column

Tags: r, svm, text-processing

I am looking for some method, that is able to classify variable based on one string column. I was told that SVM should handle it but I'm not sure how.

This is the example of data I have, I would like to classify category based on names:

```
                                                                       names                    category
321                                             Friall Táborské krokety 750g Americké brambory a krokety
800                                                    McCain Fri'Style 600g Americké brambory a krokety
803                                                       McCain Smiles 450g Americké brambory a krokety
935                                            Nowaco Americké brambory 750g Americké brambory a krokety
937                                                      Nowaco Krokety 300g Americké brambory a krokety
1375                                    Tesco Kořeněné bramborové dílky 750g Americké brambory a krokety
939                                           Nowaco Pstruh lososovitý filet                 Balené ryby
1157       Rybářství Chlumec Nad Cidlinou Kapr půlka s kůží čerstvá chlazená                 Balené ryby
1158       Rybářství Chlumec Nad Cidlinou Kapr řízky s kůží čerstvě chlazené                 Balené ryby
1159 Rybářství Chlumec Nad Cidlinou Pstruh kuchaný s hlavou čerstvý chlazený                 Balené ryby
322                                                Gastro Camping salát 140g               Balené saláty
323                                               Gastro Ďábelský salát 140g               Balené saláty
324                                             Gastro Feferonový salát 140g               Balené saláty
325                                            Gastro Hermelínový salát 140g               Balené saláty
326                                              Gastro Holandský salát 140g               Balené saláty
327                                            Gastro Loupežnický salát 140g               Balené saláty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem using [a great tutorial by François de Ryckel](https://fderyckel.github.io/2016-12-07-Texts_Classification_in_R/#introduction-of-text-analysis-with-r)
.

The solution is basically a library `tm` and `caret` in R, which helps to do various operations with text for efficient data mining. A simple example at the page gives the user basic knowledge that he needs to have to start with text processing.

Answer (score 0):

Most machine learning algorithms require inputs to be numeric. There exist multiple ways to extract numerical features from any string. Features could be: #letters, #words, or dummies indicating the presence of certain words (you can have as many as there are unique words in the set of words included in the column "names"). Of course, multiple other techniques exist, and which ones will be most effective depends on the data at hand. It is clear that domain expertise can greatly assist here. Also, sometimes deterministic rules can capture already the bulk of the cases.. So, I would not focus on finding the right ML algorithm to use, rather on which features to extract from this string and then comparing multiple algorithms.